# Connection Between Gaussian Fourier Transform and Minimal Uncertainty

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, fourier-transform

1. The Fourier Transform of a Gaussian is a Gaussian.
2. In QM, we get minimal uncertainty for a (normalized) Gaussian wave packet: $\Delta x\cdot \Delta p=\hbar /2$
   Does the second fact has nothing to do with the first?

Comment: More on [Gaussian wave packets](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+Gaussian+wave+packet).